# How to get list of disabled elements on page using Cypress

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

How to get a list of disabled elements on a page using Cypress?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A disabled html element has `disabled` attribute, e.g.:

```html
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" disabled>
```

to find such elements in Cypress could be achieved with [`.get()` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get):

```javascript
cy
  .get('[disabled]')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but web elements does not have disabled property. then how to get list of disabled elements?

Comment: @RaoThota Then you need to update your question and tell us more. Find out how those disabled elements differ and then go write a selector for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.get("#name").should('have.attr', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Hi,  and welcome to SQA stack exchange. Could you please edit your answer to explain how your answer improves on the existing answer?